# Bootstrap input addon on right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header-div on my Site. Inside the header I want to have a login-form in-line on the right side.

**css:**

```
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 5;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #ccc;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#header div {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    /*padding: 4px;*/
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#submitButton {
  float:right;
}
```

**html:**

```
<div id="header">
<div id="login">
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="row">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitButton">Login</button>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>

            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>

            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

That's what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/n5qmc/254/

But if I go in the password form and press TAB I don't get in the email input field. Because of the float:right thing. I need to do this somehow different.

What is the right way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: try shift + tab and you got your answer :p

Comment: Well your code is not good. In big screen password is first but as we will resize password is second then tab-index will change their working..

Comment: do you want addon icons on right side??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `tabindex` but as your html is not good and in bootstrap you have used your own style so tabindex got different behaviour.

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoLion/oce20q1w/2/) with changes in html and css. Please check and let me know if its ok for you..

I have removed float and also removed extra margin which were causing problem now if you will use tab then it will go one by one and also will work better in resizing. I have also changed html so email field will be first in both case.

Comment: The whole thing. All input-fields and the button.

Comment: yes like this, but with much less space between the input-fields and the button.

Comment: one min plz. updating

Comment: The heaer is completely missing :-/. I have this header-div no matter what. I just need the input-fields in this header on the right side.